# how to extenalize db connection stuff

Tags: java, oracle, spring-mvc

I am new in Java Spring framework and related technologies. I want to externalize the database stuff like connection string, username and password in a different file so that incase there is change in the database username and or password, I can go an change without touching the war file and recompiling the application. Right now all the application I am supporting was hardcoded
Any help will be appreciated. NB we are oracle shop

Comment: use `.properties` files and the `@Value("${your.property.name}")` for the injection by spring

Answer (score 1):

Use `properties` files.
This is an example of configuring `Oracle` database:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:orcl
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver.class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

and in your config class file use something like:

```
@Primary
public DataSource userDataSource() {

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource
      = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(
      env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver.class"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));

    return dataSource;
}
```

Depending on your needs, there are a lot of tutorials on the web. Check for example:
https://www.programmergate.com/spring-boot-jpa-hibernate-oracle/